# Error in assembly.cs file when working with GMap library

Tags: c#

The main form hosts gMapControl from the GMap.WindowsForms library. After starting the project, an error is generated in the Assembly.cs file, or it asks to specify the path to the assembly.cs file.

Error code Unhandled exception of the "System.StackOverflowException" type in mscorlib.dll
The "[19116] WindowsFormsApp12.exe" program terminated with the code 4294967295 (0xffffffffff).

or with the error code

The program "[20596] WindowsFormsApp12.exe" has terminated with the code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIWfK.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/66FO6.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/67rRr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the main window there is a component gMapControl, which should represent a map, but the form does not open because of errors written in the body

Comment: Either it opens and then closes immediately